# Can I get bison to make yytname externally visible?

Tags: parsing, error-handling, syntax-error, bison

Bison generates at table of tag names when processing my grammar, something like

```c
static const char *const yytname[] =
{
  "$end", "error", "$undefined", "TAG", "SCORE",
...
}
```

The `static` keyword keeps `yytname` from being visible to other parts of the code.

This would normally be harmless, but I want to format my own syntax error messages instead of relying on the ones provided to my `yyerror` function.

My makefile includes the following rule:

```
chess1.tab.c: chess.tab.c
    sed '/^static const.*yytname/s/static//' $? > $@

This works, but it's not what I'd call elegant.
```

Is there a better way to get at the table of tag names?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the table using a function which you add to your parser file:

```
%token-table
%code provides {
  const char* const* get_yytname(void);
}
...
%%
...
%%
const char* const* get_yytname(void) { return yytname; }
```

You probably also want to re-export some of the associated constants.

Alternatively, you could write a function which takes a token number and returns the token name. That does a better job of encapsulation; the existence of the string table and its precise type are implementation details.

Comment: Thanks. THat looks like the right solution. I'm running a make to see if that works the way I want.